# Java code efficiency. Should I use a switch?

Tags: android, switch-statement

Okay my problem is with this

```
        switch (charType) {
    case Mush:
        switch (charColor) {
        case Blue:
            switch (charDirec) {
            case Left:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.l_blue_m);
                break;
            case Right:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.r_blue_m);
                break;
            case Bounce:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.b_blue_m);
                break;
            case Walk:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.w_blue_m);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case Red:
            switch (charDirec) {
            case Left:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.l_red_m);
                break;
            case Right:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.r_red_m);
                break;
            case Bounce:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.b_red_m);
                break;
            case Walk:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.w_red_m);
                break;
            }
        case Tan:
            switch (charDirec) {
            case Left:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.l_tan_m);
                break;
            case Right:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.r_tan_m);
                break;
            case Bounce:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.b_tan_m);
                break;
            case Walk:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.w_tan_m);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    case Slime:
        switch (charColor) {
        case Blue:
            switch (charDirec) {
            case Left:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.l_blue_s);
                break;
            case Right:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.r_blue_s);
                break;
            case Bounce:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.b_blue_s);
                break;
            case Walk:
                bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        mainContext.getResources(), R.drawable.w_blue_s);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

What is a better way to handle this? or is this correct??

Comment: if you like to rewrite much: [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Comment: How often does the code need to run?

Comment: I have another question with the animation class. I'm trying to make it so I could change states before it draws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by splitting your method into two simpler methods. One method should find the correct resource ID, and the other actually fetches the `Bitmap`:

```
int resourceId = getResourceId(charType, charColor, charDirec);
bitmap = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    mainContext.getResources(), resourceId);
```

This simple change already removes a lot of the duplicated code.

In your `getResourceId` method you may want to consider using a map to find the resource id instead of nested switches.

```
Map<CharKey, Integer> map = new HashMap<CharKey, Integer>();

int getResourceId(charType, charColor, charDirec)
{
    CharKey key = new CharKey(charType, charColor, charDirec);
    return map.get(key).intValue();
}
```

All that remains is to populate the dictionary when your program starts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using enums for charType, charColor, charDirec - If you change to ints, you could simply make a 3D array, and use those as the index.  Prepopulate it once at application startup, this would look something like

```
int[][][] resources;

public void initResources(int numTypes, int numColors, int numDirections) {
  resources = new int[numTypes][numColors][numDirections];
  resources[MUSH][BLUE][LEFT] = R.drawable.l_blue_m;
  resources[MUSH][BLUE][RIGHT] = R.drawable.r_blue_m;
  // etc etc
}
```

then you can access the IDs later like so:

```
int resourceID = resources[charType][charColor][charDirec];
bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    mainContext.getResources(), resourceID);
```

This way your application doesn't need to navigate a switch statement every time it wants to look up a bitmap ID, just access the relevant index in a multidimensional array.